# confusion regarding the concept of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

I was reading principles of mathematical analysis by Walter Rudin chapter 2 when a confusion about the definition of a function cropped up. (Read definition in comment below) I had thought that functions were maps from
 a set called the domain to another called the codomain.  From what i knew before, these maps should not be one-many. Otherwise it would simply be a Relation not a function. But the book in its definition does not talk about the fact that functions should not be one-many. Infact it doesnt differentiate between  a general mapping and a function and puts no restriction on what a function can be. So my question is where exactly is the mistake?

UPDATE: The discussion till now points that maybe the "an" word in the definition points towards uniqueness of image $f(x)$ of an element $x$ in the domain. I have  also commented below regarding "well-defined functions" and "not well-defined functions". I think the notion of "well-defined"ness has got to do with differences in the output for the same input in various "forms" rather than just an element in the domain mapping to various elements in the range. Hence it does not in anyway interfere with the notion that a "function" cannot be one-many. Also to make things clear, Rudin uses the word "or" in conjunction with the word "mapping" and "function". Hence he is essentially saying that the mapping is a function and a function is a mapping. Which also implies that relations in general are not mapping. Please correct me if I've been wrong.

Comment: As I don't have the book handy, I don't know the exact words Rudin uses. Knowing that might make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: **Definition 2.1** Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever, and suppose that with each element $x$ of $A$ there is associated, in some manner, an element of $B$, which we denote by $f(x)$. Then $f$ is said to be a _function_ from $A$ to $B$ (or a _mapping_ of $A$ into $B$). The set $A$ is called the _domain_ of $f$ (we also say $f$ is defined on $A$), and the elements $f(x)$ are called the values of $f$. The set of all values of $f$ is called the _range_ of $f$.

Comment: @swanar You appear to be correct - it does not seem that Rudin gives the exact definition. That being said, it is not a good idea to get hung up on this sort of thing. Being precise is only good until it begins to interfere with actual learning. Do catch the little imprecisions Rudin makes as you read, but if the intended meaning is obvious like here (when he says function, he means function the way you mean function) then it is better to acknowledge it and move on rather than come to a complete stop. Mathematical literature is rarely as precise as your "intro to mathematics" textbook.

Comment: "an element of $B$" --- why do you say Rudin does not rule out one-many? I think it's pretty clear that he does.

Comment: i agree with gerry. Maybe i misinterpreted the language. When i asked someone about this, he said that a "well defined function" must not be one many but function which is not "well defined" maybe one to many. is he wrong by saying that?

Comment: I do not think there is any ambiguity in the quoted definition - after all it takes an element of $B$ and names it $f(x)$. Note also that a relation need not associate any element of $B$ with $x$.

Comment: A "function" which is not well-defined is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from the definition given in Rudis above: suppose that for each element $x$ of $A$ there is associated, in some manner, an element $b$ of $B$ ...

the linguistic interpretation rests on the word 'an' indicating that with each element in the domain $A$ there is associated just one (precisely one, exactly one, more than zero and less than two) element in $B$. Thus, it is to be understood that Rudin excludes multivalued functions as well as functions allowed to not attain a value at a point.

The more rigorous definition of function in terms of a relation specifying a certain condition might appeal to some since it is more rigorous but it also serves to obscure the process-like nature that one usually associates with the word 'function'. This is especially true in analysis where the subject matter is the study of the analytic properties of functions and not the set-theoretic issues of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Rudin gives the following definition:

> **Definition 2.1** Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, whose elements may be any objects whatsoever, and suppose that with each element $x$ of $A$ there is associated, in some manner, an element of $B$, which we denote by $f(x)$. Then $f$ is said to be a function from $A$ to $B$ (or a mapping of $A$ into $B$). The set $A$ is called the domain of $f$ (we also say $f$ is defined on $A$), and the elements $f(x)$ are called the values of $f$. The set of all values of $f$ is called the *range* of $f$.

In contrast:

> **Definition:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two arbitrary sets. We say their *cartesian product*, denoted, $A\times{B}$, is the set $\{(a,b)\mid a\in{A}\ \mbox{and }b\in{B}\}$. That is the cartesian product is the set of all ordered pairs of elements in $A$ and $B$. A  *(binary) relation*, $R$, is any subset of $A\times{B}$.

Thus the definitions are quite distinct. So, because I have a relation between two sets, does not imply I have a function. Whereas, a function is a special kind of relation.

See here, a function is described as functional, elements in the domain are related to distinct elements in the codomain and left-total: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. Rudin should really have said, "there is associated, in some manner, a *unique* element $b \in B$".  Without inserting this key word, the definition allows $f$ to be multivalued.

Comment: I disagree, Rudin's definition is unambiguous (and correct).

Comment: @did Well what part of Rudin's definition ensures that $f(x)$ is unique?  If I say, "For every cause, there is an effect", do you interpret that as meaning for a given cause there is one and only one effect?

Comment: The part which says *with each element x of A there is associated, in some manner, an element of B*. If some elements in A had no associated element of B, one would say *one or zero*. If some had more than one, one would write *one or more*.

Comment: @did Are you telling me that $\forall x \exists! y $ and $\forall x \exists y $ are the same?

Comment: Sure, this is exactly what I meant to say, suuure... You are absolutely right, Rudin was a dimwit who never managed to grasp the difference between $\exists$ and $\exists!$, ha ha ha. Right. More seriously, since you decidedly left the realm of civility for the realm of trollism, I think it is better to leave you with your certainties. Bye.

Comment: @did With a comment like that, I'll leave it to you to decide who really has "left the realm of civility."

Comment: In normal English usage the relative clause in ‘an element of $B$, which we denote by $f(x)$’ implies that the element is unique. If this is not the case in your idiolect, you’re not speaking the same language as most of us.